# Pandoc and source code highlighting: disable embedded styles when exporting to HTML

Tags: html, css, syntax-highlighting, pandoc

I just noticed that Pandoc exports some default CSS styles inline in the document when exporting markdown with code in it to HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.sourceCode { overflow-x: auto; }
  table.sourceCode, tr.sourceCode, td.lineNumbers, td.sourceCode {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; vertical-align: baseline; border: none; }
  table.sourceCode { width: 100%; line-height: 100%; }
  td.lineNumbers { text-align: right; padding-right: 4px; padding-left: 4px; color: #aaaaaa; border-right: 1px solid #aaaaaa; }
  td.sourceCode { padding-left: 5px; }
  code > span.kw { color: #007020; font-weight: bold; } /* Keyword */
  code > span.dt { color: #902000; } /* DataType */
  code > span.dv { color: #40a070; } /* DecVal */
  code > span.bn { color: #40a070; } /* BaseN */
  code > span.fl { color: #40a070; } /* Float */
  code > span.ch { color: #4070a0; } /* Char */
  code > span.st { color: #4070a0; } /* String */
  code > span.co { color: #60a0b0; font-style: italic; } /* Comment */
  code > span.ot { color: #007020; } /* Other */
  code > span.al { color: #ff0000; font-weight: bold; } /* Alert */
  code > span.fu { color: #06287e; } /* Function */
  code > span.er { color: #ff0000; font-weight: bold; } /* Error */
  code > span.wa { color: #60a0b0; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; } /* Warning */
  code > span.cn { color: #880000; } /* Constant */
  code > span.sc { color: #4070a0; } /* SpecialChar */
  code > span.vs { color: #4070a0; } /* VerbatimString */
  code > span.ss { color: #bb6688; } /* SpecialString */
  code > span.im { } /* Import */
  code > span.va { color: #19177c; } /* Variable */
  code > span.cf { color: #007020; font-weight: bold; } /* ControlFlow */
  code > span.op { color: #666666; } /* Operator */
  code > span.bu { } /* BuiltIn */
  code > span.ex { } /* Extension */
  code > span.pp { color: #bc7a00; } /* Preprocessor */
  code > span.at { color: #7d9029; } /* Attribute */
  code > span.do { color: #ba2121; font-style: italic; } /* Documentation */
  code > span.an { color: #60a0b0; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; } /* Annotation */
  code > span.cv { color: #60a0b0; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; } /* CommentVar */
  code > span.in { color: #60a0b0; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; } /* Information */
</style>
```

As I have my styles in a referenced CSS file already (using the `--css` option), I want to prevent this. How can it be done?

Comment: Since all these styles are related to highlighting, would if work if you just disable the synax highlighting? i.e. the `--no-highlight` option.

Comment: you can also change your pandoc HTML template and remove the lines with `$highlighting-css$`